# Default value of errno variable

Tags: c, errno

I want to use the errno library in order to define the return of a project (c language) functions. And I'm wondering about something...

I will do something like this :

```
#include <errno.h>

int myfunction (void)
{
  int res;

  /*Some actions....*/

  if(success)
    res = 0;
  else if (fail)
    res = -EIO;

  return res;
 }
```

I like to always initialize my local variable and I am wondering what should be the default value of a variable using the errno value (probably 0) ? But I don't really like to set by default : "SUCCESS" I prefer a "Failure" value. What is your point of view (or rule) about it ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: What does `errno` have to do with this? IIRC, you should always set `errno = 0` before calling the library function because it's not guaranteed that the library function sets it to 0 on success.

Comment: Errno is the property of the kernel and standard lib. Define your own global variable if you insist on repeating that mistake, else just define return values.

Comment: If the question is "what should I put after `int res =` at the beginning of the function", I suppose it might come down to how you are actually checking for success/fail.  Presumably you don't actually have a fall-through like you show in your sample code where perhaps neither success nor fail is true....

Comment: You shouldn't put a value for res - as if you do you remove the compiler warning that will otherwise tell you if you accidentally have a path through your function that doesn't initialize it.

Answer (score 5):

If your question is what the default, no error, value is for `errno` and all the functions that return error status in `errno`, that value is `0` as you expect.

But the error code is usually not returned as a negative value to the caller as you have it in your snippet.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `EGENERIC`/`EUNKNOWN` value defined as some general error indicator.

You have the following options:

- Be optimistic and set the default result to `0` indicating success.
- Use a function specific default out of the set of values defined for `errno`.
- <strike>If returning negative values for `errno` use `1` as generic error value.</strike>
- Use positive `errno` value and use `-1` as generic error indicator.

For the last options also set `errno` inside your function.

---

**Update on POSIX systems**

If going to use the value defined for `errno` there is no portable way to use any other value but `0`, as [POSIX explicitly states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03):

> Only the macro names <sup>*1</sup> should be used in programs, since the actual value of the error number is unspecified.

<sup>*1 This referrs to the `Exyz` macros, [as listed here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html)</sup>